# Import CSV file into MySQL table, only the first row imported

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I try to import a csv file into MySQL database.
**CSV file** : have some email addresses separated with comma(file name is "email.csv")
**MySQL database** : (database name is "test") have two column (id, email) *id* is INT, primary key and auto incremented, *email* is VARCHAR
**OS** : Microsoft windows XP
when I try to use the following command :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:\email.csv" INTO TABLE test.email FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (id,email);
```

but only 1 row inserted (The result is shown below):

```
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.06 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1
```

What should I do to

Comment: Can you show your file, 5 lines of it for example

Comment: My csv file is like: example1@yahoo.com,example2@yahoo.com,example3_ma@yahoo.com,example4@gmail.com,example5@yahoo.com

Comment: maybe mysql found only one \r\n delimiter in the end of this row? try to add end of the line after each email.

Comment: You want to import email addresses separated by comma and your line terminater is `\r\n`, your CSV should contain an email address on every line not separated by comma, or change the line terminater in import command

Comment: I think that my problem is because of I don't realize the difference between FIELDS TERMINATED and LINES TERMINATED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your csv file is like this:

```
example1@yahoo.com,example2@yahoo.com,example3_ma@yahoo.com,example4@gmail.com,e‌​xample5@yahoo.com
```

you could use this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\email.csv' INTO TABLE prova.email
LINES TERMINATED BY ',' (email);
```

you need to read every email, and put it in a new row, so what you need is a `LINES TERMINATED BY ','`, rows are then read this way:

```
example1@yahoo.com
example2@yahoo.com
example3_ma@yahoo.com
example4@gmail.com
e‌​xample5@yahoo.com
```